# How do prevent my div from spilling outside its parent container?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code taken from the codepen: http://codepen.io/rags4developer/pen/ONoBpm

Please help me to fix these problems.

1. How do I prevent the the main div & footer from spilling out of the container div ? overflow: hidden for container will not always work !
2. How do I make the container div height equal to page height without setting its height to a fixed percentage ?

**HTML:**

```
<body>
 <div id="container">
   <div id="nav">nav links 1,2,3 etc</div>
   <div id="main">
     <!--no text here-->
     <div id="left">left panel</div>
     <div id="right">right panel</div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">footer</div>
 </div> 
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
html {height: 100%;}
body {height: 100%;}
#container {
  border: 8px solid yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav {
  border: 4px solid red;
  height: 15%;
}

#main {
  border: 4px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  background: gray;
}

#left {
  border-top: 4px solid green;
  border-left: 4px solid green;
  border-bottom: 4px solid green;
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  height:100%;
  /*I will make this gradient later*/
  background: #9e9999;
}

#right {
  border: 4px solid blue;
  float: right;
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
  background: white;
}

#footer {
  border: 4px solid pink;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: have you tried learning about flexbox?

Comment: Yes, I read about it briefly. Browser support is still not good.

Comment: False. [Browser support is excellent](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure if I understand you correctly, but your heights (i.e. the heights within the `#container` div) add up to 15% + 100% + the height of the footer = at least 115% of the `#container` height plus the footer height, which causes the "spilling over".

I changed the `#content` height to `80%` and added `height: 5%;` to the footer in this fork of your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKeOdm

Now everything remains within the `#container`. Is this what you want?

Comment: Actually, I wanted the nav, content and footer = 100% of container. Container should stretch vertically to fill page, even if it does not have enough content to fill the page. If there is a lot of content, then I don't mind the page having scollbar.

Answer (score 0):

The *clearfix* solution still works well for floated elements, IMO.  Try removing the height styles and add this:

```css
#main:before,
#main:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
}

#main:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Further:  http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: I removed the main height and added your code. Now, the floated elements and footer do not expand vertically till the bottom of the container.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean about expanding vertically, can you explain?  I'm wondering why you want the container set to the page height instead of letting the height grow organically based on the content.  If you _must_ have the height equal the page height, you'll most likely want to use JS to acheive this.

Answer (score 0):

Using display table should fix this.

```
#container {
    border: 8px solid yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    **display: table;**
}

#content {
    border: 4px solid black;
    background: gray;
    height: 100%;/*Not sure 100% of what ? Parent ???*/
    **display: table-row;**
}
```